# How to rename include file from SDL.h to SDL2/SDL.h in CMake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, sdl

On Windows the name for the SDL header file is `SDL.h`, i.e., I have to use `#include <SDL.h>`, while on all other platforms it's `SDL2/SDL.h`, i.e., `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`. How can I rename this include directory in CMake, so that I don't have to conditionally check it everywhere in my files. So instead of using this:

```cpp
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
#include <SDL.h>
#else
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#endif
```

I want to simply use `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` everywhere and let CMake convert the name beforehand.

Comment: Create a file called `my_sdl.h` with the presented code and include `my_sdl.h`........

Comment: @KamilCuk that's something I try to avoid

Comment: FWIW the SDL installation I have on my windows machine is under an SDL2 folder. Could you not just put the header files in a folder called SDL2?

Comment: @SafelyFast Unfortunately not, since I apparently have to change various paths in the CMake files provided by them.